# Online PPP Services?

Tags: gps, satellite, geodesy, precise-point-positioning

I search different online PPP (PRECISE POINT POSITIONING) services, but I am new in geodesy, so I can find only a few services like:

1. CSRS-PPP (Canada)
2. GPS Analysis and Positioning Software (GAPS)
3. magicGNSS

Are there any other PPP services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also use APPS (https://pppx.gdgps.net/)
It's a technology from NASA's Jet Propulsion Laboratory and they use there own GipsyX/RTGx software for processing the GPS measurements.